# Как в JAVA подключить базу данных Access 2003?

Tags: access, java

Как в JAVA подключить базу данных Access 2003?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно использовать JDBC ODBC драйвер. Подробнее, например, тут: [Use Microsoft Access with Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-09/03-qa-0922-access.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "cy6erGn0m"